# Live CallStack in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging, callstack

Is it possible to make a 'Live' callstack window? To see the Call Stack as the application runs, automatically getting updated?

This would be great to view what happends under the hood while running my web application.

Answer (score 4):

[Runtime Flow](http://www.svprogramming.net/runtime-flow/index.html) (developed by me) shows a call stack of a running .NET application updated in real time. You can see all function calls up to the moment in a call stack tree.

Answer (score 3):

I doubt it... even if it was available, then the update rate on it would be so fast that you wouldn't be able to see anything. Just put [Trace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) statements in the functions you're interested in.

```
Trace.WriteLine("Foo::Bar()");
```

You can view the `Trace` results in your Output window as you're debugging. If you have the need for more advanced tracing, then use the [dotTrace profiler](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) or any other .NET profiler.

Answer (score 2):

This would be technically possible but it would be essentially an unusable feature.  In a normal running application the call stack changes ... easily thousands of times a second.  There is simply no way for the UI to keep up with that kind of throughput in a meaningful way.  If it simply painted every version on the screen it would just appear as a blur to you and bde useless.

Comment: Maybe it doesn't need to be updated that frequently. Maybe only at 10hz. That could be useful for the case where particular routines or lines of code are active a high percent of time at a stable level of the stack. Then they would appear somewhat stably while the stuff around them was just fuzzy. Especially if it can draw samples during I/O it could be quite informative.

Answer (score 1):

Every single method call?  There might be hundreds or thousands, or hundreds of thousands of call stack changes per second.  You can't do it in Visual Studio 2010.  You can suspend a `Thread` object and get a stack trace from that and output but performance will be terrible (unusable).

It sounds like you might want a profiler instead.

Answer (score 0):

I have two suggestions:

1. There's a new feature in Visual studio 16.9 that is called "New Dynamic Instrumentation Profiling for .NET"

   There's some details here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/new-dynamic-instrumentation-profiling/
2. There is this free Profiler called "codetack" which helps
   analyzing code execution. If I remember it correctly, it can show
   real-time analysis. https://www.getcodetrack.com/