# Looking for more than the regular visual studio "call stack"

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

When debugging, i can see the "Call Stack" on visual studio. But i am wondering if there is an option to see all the "call stack" from point to point somewhere?

i want to learn the flow of the application (from the code aspect) and to see all the methods the application executing during a specific flow.

is there a way to collect that information using visual studio?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Live CallStack in Visual Studio 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7502548/live-callstack-in-visual-studio-2010)

Answer (score 2):

I think you could do this with JetBrains profiler - [dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/).